# Given $x = \frac{1}{5}(4,2,2,1)^T$. Find orthonormal basis of $R^4$ that contains $x$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $x = \frac{1}{5}(4,2,2,1)^T$. Find orthonormal basis of $R^4$ that contains $x$.

I got a hint that $R$ has to be a reflection matrix which makes this equation true $Rx = e_1$ , $e_1 = [1,0,0,0]^T$. but it does not help me much, because after I find that $R$, how can I use it to construct an orthonormal basis that contains the given vector $x$?

Comment: Rotations preserve scalar products and are inversible, so if $R$ is a rotation and $e_1,\dots,e_4$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, $Re_1,\dots,Re_4$ is an orthonormal basis, and by construction it contains $x=Re_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the equation $$Rx=e_1$$ is underdetermined for $R$.

This means there are many possible $R$ fulfilling this equation.

There is a simple procedure in order to find an orthogonal basis.

To do so find any four vectors which are linear independent.
In your case it might be easy to use $x, e_2, e_3, e_4$ because they are linear independent and of the lenght 1. Which makes things easier.

Then you need $e'_2$ such that $e'_2\cdot x = 0$ but $e'_2\cdot e'_2=1$

$$e'_2=\text{n}\left(e_2-x( e_2\cdot x)\right)$$

While $\text{n}(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$ is used to make the lenght to one.

$$e'_3 = \text{n}\left(e_3-x (e_3\cdot x)-e'_2(e_3\cdot e'_2)\right)$$

and finally

$$e'_4 = \text{n}\left(e_4-x (e_4\cdot x)-e'_2(e_4\cdot e'_2)-e'_3(e_4\cdot e'_3)\right)$$

Then $x,e'_2,e'_3,e'_4$ is your orthogonal basis of $R^4$ which contains $x$.

Comment: so I do gram schimdt on $x,e2,e3,e4$ and I find the orthonormal basis?

Comment: Sorry I forgott all the names in mathematics ;(

Comment: But after googling. It seems that this guy has the same idea than me :)